# Track Internet Usage

Tags: linux, internet

I am looking to track the internet usage on linux, how can I do this? I would like to come back in x amount of time and be able to see how much data has been used.

Comment: Raw source of information is `/proc/net/dev` but presumably there are tools that will parse and process that for you.

Comment: [Relevant list on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368002/network-usage-top-htop-on-linux) | [Similar question here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67807/is-there-a-top-like-command-that-shows-the-network-bandwidths-and-file-accesses) | [Similar on SU](http://superuser.com/questions/615958/how-to-track-internet-usage-upload-download-on-linux)

Answer (score 1):

I found some really useful links on the internet. (first link also works for linux in computers)

From raspberrypi.org: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=7390

From development-cycle.com: http://www.development-cycle.com/2011/07/tracking-bandwidth-usage-with-vnstat/

The last one displays a detailed way to install vnstat in order to monitor  internet bandwidth usage.
Best of luck!